# I want to customize the react-select

Tags: html, css, reactjs

you can see the code sandbox link what my task is I need to change the arrow size too small and put it under the circle you can see their CSS I set width and height but it's not working so I need to change the swiper-button-next and swiper-button-prev to small according to UI

```
 <Select
                      className="drop-down"
                      options={data?.map((data, index) => ({
                        value: data.username,
                        label: data.username,
                        id: index,
                      }))}
                      name="user"
                      value={data.username}
                      onChange={handleSelectChangeL}
                      placeholder="User Name"
                      theme={(theme) => ({
                        ...theme,
                        colors: {
                          ...theme.colors,
                          text: "black",
                          primary25: "#d6fdf7",
                          primary: "#0bb7a7",
                          primary50: "#d6fdf7",
                        },
                      })}
                    ></Select>

                    <button
                        className="dash-button-1"
                        type="submit"
                        variant="contained"
                        onClick={reset}
                      >
                        Reset
                      </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard swiper arrows use the font so you have to make it smaller by setting the font-size:

```
.mySwiper .swiper-button-next:after, .mySwiper .swiper-button-prev:after {
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the font size for `before` and `after` button. It will work.

```
.swiper-button-next:after, .swiper-button-prev:after {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

**Working Fiddle**

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;

  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.swiper-button-prev {
  color: red;
  width: 2%;
  height: 2%;
}

.swiper-button-next {
  color: #000;
  width: 2%;
  height: 2%;
}

.mySwiper .swiper-button-next:after, .mySwiper .swiper-button-prev:after {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Swiper JS -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

<div class="swiper-container mySwiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```